# How to maintain Work Item traceability in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops

We have requirements for our project in excel format. Now i want this requirement to be upload into azure devops as work items. I have created epic ->Feature-> product backlog item -> task. we have many to many relationship among these items. We also need to create some other custom work items for scenario and use cases. These are also linked with many to many relationship.
How could i upload these data into azure devops with this complicated mapping so that nothing from the requirement will left over.
How to bulk upload this many to many mapping.

Comment: Can you show an example excel file? Without this it is quite difficult to understand what exactly you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> How to bulk upload this many to many mapping.

As far as I know, you could use the `Tree list` in Excel to bulk upload the work items.

You could create the work items with Parent-child link. Then you could add additional relationships between the work items(e.g. related , referenced).

Here are the steps:

Step1:  Connect the Azure Devops Project in `Excel -> Teams`. Then select `new list -> Input List`.

Step2: Use the `Add Tree level` option to convert the list type to `Tree type`(Parent/Child).

Step3: Create work items with `parent-child` relationship and Publish to Azure Devops Project.

Step4: Click the `Links and Attachments -> Link to` to add additional relationship.

[image]

Then click the `publish` option to update the relationship.

In this case, all relevant relationships will be reflected in azure devops.

For example:

[image]

For more detailed information about the upload steps, you could refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#import-work-items-tree-list).